# ActiveRecord Relation error when trying to display events for only today in PG

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

What I am trying to do is show just the events that are today-

```
@event = Events.where('EXTRACT(DAY FROM start) = ?', Date.today)
```

All I can get to show up is `<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007f8d06348d80>`. The page loads, but that is my showing text.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong & where? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `EXTRACT(DAY FROM start) = ?` pulls out the 'day' as in 'day of month' from the timestamp, but not the whole date.  Use `EXTRACT(DATE FROM start) = ?` or simply cast to a date using `start::date = ?`.

Besides for this, you aren't getting a single record, but a lazy loaded collection that hasn't yet been triggered.  If you expect a single record to match this `where` filter, then just append `.first` to return a single Event.  Otherwise, use `.all` or some Enumerable method ( `each`, `map`, etc.) that will trigger the query to build a collection of `Events`.

```
@event = Event.where("EXTRACT(DATE FROM start) = ?", Date.today).first
=> SELECT * FROM events WHERE EXTRACT(DATE FROM start) = '2013-01-04' LIMIT 1

@events = Event.where("EXTRACT(DATE FROM start) = ?", Date.today).all
=> SELECT * FROM events WHERE EXTRACT(DATE FROM start) = '2013-01-04'
```

At this point you have an ActiveRecord object (or collection of objects), which is not typically rendered directly, but rather through calling attributes or methods.

So instead of: `<%= @event %>`, you would use: `<%= @event.description %>` or something similar.

Comment: Using both of those I still run into the same error. 
    .where('EXTRACT(DATE FROM start) = ?', Date.today)

Comment: @keade: This is due to the lazy-loading inherent to the query API - updated to explain this.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, the `where` class method returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object so that you can keep chaining more calls to build your query like this:

```
Model.where(:a => a)
     .where('b < ?', b)
     .limit(6)
     .order(:created_at)
```

Now, an `ActiveRecord::Relation` represents several items, there might be only one match but `ActiveRecord::Relation` can't know that until it tries to pull everything out of the database. If you know there is only match then you can say:

```
@event = Event.where(...).first
```

but perhaps you should be saying:

```
@events = Event.where(...)
```

and then something like this in your view:

```
<% @events.each do |event| %>
    <!-- Display event -->
<% end %>
```

That will allow you to "show just the **events** that are today" (emphasis mine).

And see [PinnyM's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14696396/479863) for how to use EXTRACT.